# Is Base64_encode() in PHP equal to java.util.Base64?

Tags: java, php, base64, decode, encode

I want to use php to pass and get a encoded string to other system which are using `java.util.Base64` to encode and decode.
Can I use `base64_encode($str)` to encode and pass the string to them for decode in php and
can i use `base62_decode($str)` to decode what I get from `java.util.Base64` in php?
Or is there other way to encode and decode `java.util.Base64` string in php?

Thanks!!

Comment: The encoding is defined as standard in [RFC-4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648). So it should/must be the same. Due to its usage in MIME, imagine e.g. a mail client written in java/c#. It would be worse, if your data is in interpreted in different ways :)

Comment: Base64 encoding/decoding must be the same in PHP or Java. But beware there may be a difference depending on whether it considers text or binary data. There may also be a difference in character string encoding (UTF-8,...)

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: **Yes**.

Base64 is a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Long Answer:

The [PHP documentation for base64_encode](http://php.net/base64_encode) references [RFC 2045](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2045.html) which is the MIME base64 encoding.

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) tells that Java supports different types of Base64, one of which is MIME. The Basic type should also work. The main difference is that the MIME type requires that no line is longer than 76 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, base64 is a standard that should work the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, a standard format across different platform and language.