# base64_encode() from php function to Java does not return same data

Tags: java, php, base64, encode

I'm working on a java project that needs to have an authentication from accounts created on a local website. Those account's passwords are encrypted by a php function before inserted to the database :

```
public function crypter($mdp){
    $j = 0;
    $tmp = 0;
    $key = $mdp;

    $res = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($mdp) ; $i++)
    {
        $tmp = ord($mdp[$i]) + ord($key[$i]);
        if($tmp > 255){
            $tmp = $tmp - 256;
        }

        $res[$i] = chr($tmp);

        if($j == strlen($key)-1){
            $j = 0;
        }
        else{
            $j = (($j % (strlen($key))) +1 );
        }
    }

    $res = base64_encode($res);

    return $res;
}
```

NOTE : This function has not been written by me, so if you guys figure out what the `$j` variable is used for let me know. I also (obviously) can not change this code.

So I've tried to translate that function in Java which gave this :

```
public String cryptMdp(String mdp){
    String res = "";
    String key = mdp;

    int j = 0;
    int tmp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mdp.length(); i++) {
        char c = mdp.charAt(i);
        char c2 = key.charAt(i);

        tmp = (int) c + (int) c2;
        if (tmp > 255) {
            tmp = tmp - 256;
        }

        res += (char) tmp;

        if (j == key.length() - 1){
            j = 0;
        }
        else{
            j = (j % key.length()) + 1;
        }
    }
    return Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(res.getBytes());
}
```

Unfortunately, those do not return the same string (ex: For the string `a`, php returns `wg==` and Java returns `w4I=`.), even though according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728951/is-base64-encode-in-php-equal-to-java-util-base64) this is supposed to be a standard.

Can you guys see what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Chk this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002603/base64-encode-different-between-java-and-php

Comment: @Penguine Already saw it, but this guy solution was the use of hmac, which I'm not using in my case

Comment: Check charset in java and php. They can be different. And another thing - java use wchar in its string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to do what I want using URLConnection to send a HTTP request to my PHP page, like so :

```
public String cryptMdp(String mdp){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://myaddress/someproject/create_pwd.php?pwd=" + mdp);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputline = "";

        while((inputline = in.readLine()) != null){
            return inputline;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("error URL");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("error connection");
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem was that the PHP was using unknown characters before encoding them, which means that all of the passwords are incorrectly crypted...

EDIT :

Actually the password is crypted differently in the IDE (Netbeans) and in the builded app (.jar), so `Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(res.getBytes());` actually produce the same as the PHP method...

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing Java functionality for Base64:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

You are probably looking for this method:

encode(byte[] src)
Encodes all bytes from the specified byte array into a newly-allocated byte array using the Base64 encoding scheme.

Comment: Sill not working :( I've tried `Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode()`, `Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString()`, `Base64.getEncoder().encode()` and `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString()` I'm getting the same result with all of them

Comment: Are you 150% sure that the inputs are the same?

Comment: Compare them directly and make sure there are no invisible characters anywhere.

Comment: You could also try debugging both methods to see at which point exactly the outputs start deviating. That should give you a hint where to find the problem.